# Ansible and sudo

Tags: ansible, sudo

I'm trying to run a role against multiple machines and multiple users. I have the following playbook:

```
- name: Install dotfiles across hosts
  hosts: was
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ item }}"
  vars:
    users:
      - wasadm
      - ihsadm
  tasks:
    - name: Execute role as specific user
      ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: installProfile
        apply:
          become: true
          become_user: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

And the following role:

```
#======  ANSIBLE  ============================================================
#          NAME:  tasks/main.yml
#   DESCRIPTION:  Primary entry point for this play
#=============================================================================
---
- name: Remove dotfiles pull
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /home/{{ ansible_user_id }}/.dotfiles
    state: absent

- name: Extract dotfiles zip
  ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: /var/tmp/dotfiles.zip
    dest: /home/{{ ansible_user_id }}
    owner: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
  notify:
    - executeInstallation

- name: Remove dotfiles archive
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /var/tmp/dotfiles.zip
    state: absent
```

I'm not sure what variable I should be using in the role. `ansible_user_id` defaults to the executing user (ansibleadm in this case) and not the sudo user. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: just drop the owner stanza and the file will be created with the become user as owner. And in `dest` simply use `item` which is the user in the loop of your include task.

Comment: it doesnt appear to be doing the sudo. I added this to the role:

- name: Basic usage
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "'{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'USER') }}' is the HOME environment variable."

and it consistently prints the ssh user account. Is there a variable that houses the username AFTER the sudo, or is this just not doing the sudo at all? I'm not sure tbh

Comment: Please [do not add needed information to answer your question in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). [edit] your answer. Moreover, please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Thanks.

Comment: uhh, ok. not sure what i did wrong, I'm just providing more info. if you want me to delete this question then say so.

Comment: You are adding more info in comments when you should [edit] your question instead. And even with those precisions, your question does not contain a [mre]. Good luck.